# Switch to another window of the same application

Tags: windows-10

I opened two firefox windows on platform of windows 10.  I remembered that Control+~(grave) could switch to the other window of the same application.

But it failed on windows10. How could I get such a shourtcut?

Comment: Are they two tabs in the same window, or two completely separate windows?

Comment: CTRL+` is not a Windows OS command. It's used in Excel to switch cells, and is may be a command on MacOS, but Microsoft has not given it a set value in Windows. Alt+Tab is the standard command to switch between applications. It defaults to opening the previous window first, and so can easily be used to switch back and forth between 2 windows even if other programs are open.

Comment: two completely separate windows. @music2myear

Comment: Then just ALT+Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> to switch to an application on a tray based on its position.

> Windows logo key  + number:   Open the desktop and start the app pinned to the taskbar in the position indicated by the number. If the app is already running, switch to that app.

[Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445)

If you press the number multiple times you can switch between instances of the same application.

Comment: amazing, is it possible to define Control+grave to get it done with autohotkey?

Comment: I've never used autohotkey, so don't know.